# Packet loss when configuring multiple networks Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: networking

I have previously had this set up working, but it's not working now ... I was wondering if anyone could shine some light on this for me.

Here's my network config:

```
#internet facing
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

#internal network
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

And here's my routes:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Now, when I ping an internet address (8.8.8.8) I get abour 60%-70% packet loss.

But, if I `ifdown` eth1 (The internal network), it gets no packet loss. Does anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Well, I may be wrong but I'm assuming that you get latency & loss because of the system having multiple gateways (one gateway for each NIC). Also looking at the routing table, I don't see default or user specific routes mentioned with gateways in-order to send the packets out to the internet. A proper routes in place should fix.

Comment: Yeah the default route is there ... I found a way around it though (Not related to this question), so I might just delete this question, because I won't be able to implement anyone's answer now ...

Comment: Don't use `network` and `broadcast`. The computer will calculate those properly from `address` and `netmask`.  Would have been better with `ip -n route` so we got IP numbers.

Comment: Well, @Stretch... even the default route does not show any gateways at all.. Nevertheless, good luck. If you need to assistance, please don't hesitate to post back or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two separate NIC's for each interface?  To the best of my knowledge, a single NIC can't run on two separate networks, so if you're configuring it to behave like such, that could explain your packet loss.

Have you looked into doing a bridge on your interfaces?

Comment: No, they are 2 separate nics

Comment: You can have one NIC on many networks. It will be a bit messy, but you can. Why you would want to have that,  I wouldn't know though.